# Android: parse.com query

Tags: android, database, parse-platform

I am using Parse as database.
I would like to ask if there are over 1000 items in the Data_db, where the username is unique.

### Code:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Data_db");                 
    query.whereEqualTo("username", edittext_user.getText().toString());
    query.setLimit(1);
```

### Question:

While I know fetching over 1000 dataset we need to use the `.setSkip(1000)` function and performing looping, I would like to ask how about querying a specific user? Is it also limited to the first 1000 rows? and if yes, how could such user beyond 1000 could be queried?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this the wrong way, your query will be inefficient as you're looking **1 object** when those constraints through an entire class, regardless of it being already found. It would be better to use `getFirstInBackground()`. Something like:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Data_db");                 
query.whereEqualTo("username", edittext_user.getText().toString());
query.getFirstInBackground(...);
```

A maximum of 1000 objects can be *returned to you* through a single query, by using `getFirstInBackground()`, you're searching though the database, hence that limitation is not applied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice! I really have not thought about this before...and I know that parse got limit of 1000...what if the user to be searched is located at index 1020 in the table, would the codes in question or your advice still work, or would the query end at user#1000 and return nil? (presently my db does not have such volume of data and hence could not be tested)

Comment: No its not like that, the query can RETURN up-to a 1000 objects to you, searching through the database is not limited by this condition. Updated answer

Comment: thanks, that means it can query more than 1000 objects (all the items in the db) query would not stop at #1000 and return at max 1000 findings